# Permission denial when calling from Android fragment. Uses-permission IS set

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I got a little problem here and it is driving me crazy.
I want to call a person with the *ACTION_CALL* intent in Android and I do it with the following code in a fragment:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       Ansat a = container.adapter.getItem(position);
       callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + a.mobil.replace(" ", "").trim()));
       container.startActivity(callIntent);
```

*container* is the main activity context passed to the fragment, because fragments don't have its own activity.

I have set the permission in Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<permission
    android:name="mithfogvuc.android.svhfvuc.dk.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="mithfogvuc.android.svhfvuc.dk.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NewsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="mithfogvuc.android.svhfvuc.dk.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".GCMPushReceiverService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".GCMRegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.idd.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".FravaersregistreringActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FremmoederegistreringActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
```

WHY am I getting the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: mithfogvuc.android.svhfvuc.dk, PID: 23045
      java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
      act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity }
      from ProcessRecord{6c1ee2e 23045:mithfogvuc.android.svhfvuc.dk/u0a251} (pid=23045, uid=10251) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

Comment: post android manifest.

Comment: Now with full manifest

Comment: Which OS version is this on?

Comment: are you getting this in android marshmallow?? If yes, you have to handle the permission at runtime.

Comment: Yes I am running Marshmallow (6.0.1). I wasn't aware of the new Runtime permissions, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Android 6.0 (Api lvl 23) onwards the OS allows users to **revoke** permissions from applications. You need to look into [Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

It looks like your app needs to poll one of the `requestPermissions()` methods to be granted access to the `call_phone` API!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do Like This

```
             if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                           android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        // Should we show an explanation?
                        if   

           (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                               android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {

                            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Its Necessary To Call",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]     {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);

                        } else {

                            // No explanation needed, we can request the     permission.

                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                    new String[]   {Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);

                            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                            // result of the request.
                        }
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
```